# How to process only 1/10 frames in func captureOutput

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I am doing some kind of processing on frames in following method

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {}
```

But I do not want to do it in all frames say I want 1/15 or 1/10 how can I achieve this is there any pre-build logic provided by swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a counter in your class and then increment it in *captureOutput*

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
i += 1
   if (i % 15 == 0) //every 15 frames
   {
   //process your frame
   }
}
```